# How to receive messages from unet audio with python

Tags: python, audio, communication, unetstack

we are currently testing communication using unet audio, we have downloaded unet audio on both devices on the computer and raspberry.We have successfully sent and received messages using unet audio in the terminal but we want to use python on raspberry to receive messages via unet audio.
When receiving messages via the terminal module there are no problems, but when receiving messages using Python the message cannot be received.  What is the solution to this problem?

this is the programs that we try

```
from unetpy import *
import sys

port = 1100
ip_address = 'localhost'

if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print("Usage : rxdata <ip_address> <rx_node_address> <port> \n"
          "ip_address: IP address of the transmitter modem. \n"
          "port: port number of transmitter modem. \n"
          "A usage example: \n"
          "rxdata.py 192.168.1.20 1100\n");
    sys.exit();

ip_address = sys.argv[1]

if (len(sys.argv) > 2):
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

print("Connecting to " + ip_address + ":" + str(port));
sock = UnetSocket(ip_address, port)
if ( sock == None ):
    print("Couldn't open unet socket");
    sys.exit();

# Bind to protocol DATA
if (not sock.bind(Protocol.DATA)):
    print("Couldn't open bind to socket");
    sys.exit();

# Set a timeout of 10 seconds
sock.setTimeout(10000);

# Receive and display data
print("Waiting for a Datagram");

ntf = sock.receive()

if (ntf != None):
    print(ntf)
else:
    print("Error receiving data")

# Close the unet socket
sock.close()

print("Reception Complete");
```

Thank you

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: How are you sending the message? UnetSocket is bound to protocol DATA, and so you will only expect to receive datagrams sent with this protocol.